# Lenovo Y500 USB 3.0 speed issues

Tags: ssd, external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, speed, usb-3

I have Lenovo Y500 laptop with Windows 8.1 Pro x64. Inside it I have SSD drive (changed it when I bought the laptop). I'm connecting to USB 3.0 ports pendrives, SSD and HDD drives. As few months ago there was no such problem, now I'm dealing with speed issues.

When I connect SanDisk Extreme pendrive with 32GB size I've noted speed from 60MB/s going down to few MB/s when writing to this drive with big file (7 GBs). When I'm using SSD drive - everything seems to be ok - external SSD drive is writing at about 160MB/s (when reading from internal SSD drive). When I use external HDD the writing speed oscillates about 55MB/s. When I use other (not WD, but Thermaltake) enclosure the writing speed is much more than 80MB/s with other drive.

What I have done so far, was removing the drivers for each drive, the USB 3.0 drivers and other similar in Manage Hardware. Also, I've tried to install Intel Rapid Storage Technology app=driver, Intel USB 3.0 drivers for Windows 7 and other Intel software, but nothing helped.

Few months ago I was writing to SanDisk Extreme at >100MB/s speed. Also sometimes I was able to write to external HDDs at 80-100MB/s.

Is there a way to come back to old transfer speeds on this Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out. The pendrive was stagnant for longer period of time. Wiping it whole with shredder helped. Now the drive can write at over 100MB/s.